# Request html label text from flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I develop a flask app that has a label in a html. The label text is inside a form and changed via javascript on user input. But if the form is submitted I call a flask route and want to get / request the label text. Request works with ranges or dropdown but it doesn't with the label for some reason. What am I missing?

Here is what works:

```
@app.route("/estimator/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def estimator():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mmm_es.online = float(request.form['range_on'])
```

and what does not work:

```
@app.route("/estimator/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def estimator():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mean_sum = request.form['spend_per_month']
```

or

```
        mean_sum = request.form.get('spend_per_month')
```

I either get "none" as a value for mean_sum or a bad request page.

The html looks something like this:

```
     <div class="col-sm-4">
         <label> Spending gesamt: </label>
         <input type="text" id="sumofspending" size=4 value={{ gesamt_sum }}> T€     </input>
         Spending pro Monat: <label style="font-weight:normal" id="spend_per_month" name="spend_per_month"> {{ mean_sum }} T€ </label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-7">
        <label> Online: </label>
        <input type="range" name="range_on" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ online }}" id="range_online" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_online)"/>
     </div>
```

The full form is:

```
<form  onsubmit="showloader()" action="/estimator/" method="POST" role="form" class="form-horizontal" style="display: inline;">
 <div class="form-group">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <label for="sel1">Geschäftsbereich:</label>
             <select class="form-control" id="pg" name="pg" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                 {% for pg_feature in pg_features %}
                    <option value="{{ pg_feature }}" {% if pg_feature==pg_select %} SELECTED {% endif %}>{{ pg_feature }}</option>
                 {% endfor %}
             </select>

         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label> GWE jetzt (%): </label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="GWE_jetzt" style="width:40px" value="{{  gwe_jetzt  }}">
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:20px;"></div>
         <!--div class="col-xs-12" style="height:25px;"> <label> KPIs jetzt: </label> </div-->

         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <label> Anfangsmonat: </label>
             <select class="form-control" id="start_month" name="start_month" onchange="update_spends_per_month()">
                 <option value="Januar"> Januar </option>
                 <option value="Februar"> Februar </option>
                 <option value="März"> März </option>
                 <option value="April"> April </option>
                 <option value="Mai"> Mai </option>
                 <option value="Juni"> Juni </option>
                 <option value="Juli"> Juli </option>
                 <option value="August"> August </option>
                 <option value="September"> September </option>
                 <option value="Oktober"> Oktober </option>
                 <option value="November"> November </option>
                 <option value="Dezember"> Dezember </option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <label> Endmonat: </label>
             <select class="form-control" id="end_month" name="end_month" onchange="update_spends_per_month()">
                 <option value="Januar"> Januar </option>
                 <option value="Februar"> Februar </option>
                 <option value="März"> März </option>
                 <option value="April"> April </option>
                 <option value="Mai"> Mai </option>
                 <option value="Juni"> Juni </option>
                 <option value="Juli"> Juli </option>
                 <option value="August"> August </option>
                 <option value="September"> September </option>
                 <option value="Oktober"> Oktober </option>
                 <option value="November"> November </option>
                 <option value="Dezember"> Dezember </option>
             </select>
         </div>
         <!--div class="col-sm-3">
            <label> GMB (%): </label>
            <!--input type="text" name="GMB_jetzt" style="width:40px" value="{{  gmb_jetzt  }}"-->
            <!--input type="text" name="GMB_jetzt" style="width:40px" value=0>
         </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label> KB (%): </label>
            <input type="text" name="KB_jetzt" style="width:40px" value=0>
         </div-->
         <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:20px;"></div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <label> Spending gesamt: </label>
             <input type="text" id="sumofspending" name="sumofspending" size=4 value={{ gesamt_sum }}> T€     </input>
             Spending pro Monat: <label style="font-weight:normal" id="spend_per_month" name="spend_per_month"> {{ mean_sum }} T€ </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-5">
             <button type="button" size=1 onclick="update_from_total()"> Gesamtspending prozentual auf genutzte Medien verteilen </button>
         </div>
         <!--div class="col-sm-4">
             <label> In Prozent: </label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="inprozent" id="inpercent" checked>
         </div-->
         <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:20px;"></div>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
              <input type="checkbox" name="gesamtprozent" value="gesamt" id="gesamtfest" {{ 'checked="checked"' if gesamt_checked else "" }} /> Gesamt fest
              <br> </br>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
         </div>

         <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> TV: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_tv" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ tv }}" id="range_tv" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_tv)"/> </input>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" id="text_tv" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(text_tv)" value="{{ tv }}"> </input> <label> T€ - </label>
             <input type="text" id="percent_tv" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(percent_tv)" value="33"> </input> <label> %  </label>
         </div>
         <!--div class="col-sm-2">
             <label id="percent_tv"> </label> %
         </div-->
         <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> Online: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_on" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ online }}" id="range_online" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_online)"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="text_online" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(text_online)" value="{{ online }}"> </input> <label> T€ - </label>
             <input type="text" id="percent_online" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(percent_online)" value="33"> </input> <label> %  </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> Publikumszeitschriften: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_pz" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ pz }}"  id="range_pz" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_pz)"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" id="text_pz" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(text_pz)" value="{{ pz }}"> </input> <label> T€ - </label>
             <input type="text" id="percent_pz" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(percent_pz)" value="33"> </input> <label> %  </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> Radio: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_radio" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ radio }}"   id="range_radio" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_radio)"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" id="text_radio" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(text_radio)" value="{{ radio }}"> </input> <label> T€ - </label>
             <input type="text" id="percent_radio" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(percent_radio)" value="0"> </input> <label> %  </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> Kino: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_kino" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ kino }}" id="range_kino" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_kino)"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" id="text_kino" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(text_kino)"  value="{{ kino }}"> </input> <label> T€ - </label>
             <input type="text" id="percent_kino" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(percent_kino)" value="0"> </input> <label> %  </label>
         </div>
         <!--div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> Mobile: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_mobile" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="{{ mobile }}" id="range_mobile" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_mobile)"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input type="text" id="text_mobile" size=1> </input> <label> T€ </label>
         </div-->
         <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> Zeitungen: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_tz" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ tz }}" id="range_tz" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_tz)"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" id="text_tz" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(text_tz)"  value="{{ tz }}"> </input> <label> T€ - </label>
             <input type="text" id="percent_tz" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(percent_tz)" value="0"> </input> <label> %  </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> Plakat: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_ooh" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ ooh }}" id="range_ooh" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_ooh)"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" id="text_ooh" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(text_ooh)"  value="{{ ooh }}"> </input> <label> T€ - </label>
             <input type="text" id="percent_ooh" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(percent_ooh)" value="0"> </input> <label> %  </label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-7">
            <label> Werbesendungen: </label>
            <input type="range" name="range_ws" min="0" max="10000" step="1" value="{{ ws }}" id="range_ws" onmousemove="update_from_rangetext(range_ws)"/>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
             <input type="text" id="text_ws" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(text_ws)"  value="{{ ws }}"> </input> <label> T€ - </label>
             <input type="text" id="percent_ws" size=1  onkeyup="update_from_rangetext(percent_ws)" value="0"> </input> <label> %  </label>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Schätze KPI's </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: can you show your full html <form>?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. Labels are for displaying things to the user, they are not for submitting data. If you want data to be sent to the backend, use an input.

Comment: I think your data will be inside form['sumofspending']

Comment: I just thought that I could use the calculated value in the label which comes from javascript. Otherwise I need to calculate it again in python which seems inconsistent.

Comment: What he means you have to query your input instead your label and in this case the input is called sumofspending

Comment: Thanks lapinkoira. I could use that and divide by number of months in python to get the value I want. I understand now that it is not wise to request the label text. If it is possible is a different question. Downvote seems a bit harsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a hidden input called 'spend_per_month' and ensure that it is updated if/when the user changes the label. As an input, it will be submitted along with the other parameters.

```
<input type="hidden" name="spend_per_month" value="" id="minput" />
```

You could also do it onsubmit, e.g. with jQuery using the `val()` method:

```
$("form").on('submit',
             function() {
                $('#minput').val($("#spend_per_month_label").text());
             });
```

(You might want to edit the id of the label element to make it clear it's the label and not the hidden input.)

Comment: To be clear, we have to include the `<input type="hidden"...>` in the HTML if we want that jQuery code to work, yes?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comments (thanks commenters):

Daniel Roseman:

> Labels are for displaying things to the user, they are not for
>   submitting data. If you want data to be sent to the backend, use an
>   input.

Requesting labels is thus neither possible nor wise. The calculations in javascript have to be done again on the server in python.